# Issue with Azure Computer Vision API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am facing an issue with Azure Computer Vision API. If I send a request with contentType = application/json and image URL in JSON request body things work fine but on sending a binary image(base 64 encoded) with contentType = application/octet-stream it gives me ImageFormatInvalid in the resp

```
[
    {
        "key": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 
        "value": "6f7ff175139e4e1d8b943c6170fe5b8e",
        "description": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "multipart/form-data",
        "description": ""
    }
]
```

Content-Type: multipart/form-data and asking input as binary image data

Comment: You might want to change your api key now

Answer (score 2):

The API expects the image in binary form, not base64 encoded. See API defintion here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa

Comment: In the interest of completeness, I would add that if the `Content-Type` is `multipart/form-data`, then the image *must* be base64-encoded.  But for `application/octet-stream`, the body should contain binary image data.

Comment: @cthrash Do you have a curl example for sending base64 data? I am not being lazy, but no joy googling for it.  Also, thank you for all your answers on Azure cognitive, please know it's appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example `curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $CV_KEY" "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v3.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Tags" -F image=@test.jpg`.

Comment: @cthrash Thank you.  I use the following to pass a file: `--data-binary "@test.jpg"`  However, my question is this: If I pre-process the file by running the base64 command and getting the base64 output ready, can I pass that text (i.e. the output from base64) to the curl command?  Thanks again.

Comment: @cthrash BTW, I tried your command and it works as well.  Good to know multiple ways of making requests.  Using my approach (i.e. with --data-binary) I also have to specify a  `"content-type: application/octet-stream"` header; otherwise I get an "UnsupportedMediaType" error.  Your approach with fewer arguments has less moving parts, less opportunity for something to be misspecified.

Comment: You specifically asked for a base64 upload, which was what I provided.  Your method is preferred since you're sending fewer bytes over the wire. But as you've noted you do have to explicitly state the content type if you send raw bytes.